# using both JointTrajectoryController and JointPositionController at same time in ros_control

Tags: ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I just follow the excellent ros_control tutorial at (http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_control) and able to run robot in gazebo, that provide command interface for each joint

```
roslaunch rrbot_gazebo rrbot_world.launch
roslaunch rrbot_control rrbot_control.launch
```

Next, I'd like to control this robot from our application, so need to use JointTrajectoryAction (or FollowJointTrajectoryAction), so I added following code in rrbot_control

```
diff --git a/rrbot_control/config/rrbot_control.yaml b/rrbot_control/config/rrbot_control.yaml
index 9cbcf45..0f62b1a 100644
--- a/rrbot_control/config/rrbot_control.yaml
+++ b/rrbot_control/config/rrbot_control.yaml
@@ -13,3 +13,15 @@ rrbot:
     type: effort_controllers/JointPositionController
     joint: joint2
     pid: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
+
+  # Trajectory Controllers ---------------------------------------
+  joint_trajectory_controller:
+    type: "effort_controllers/JointTrajectoryController"
+    joints:
+      - joint1
+      - joint2
+
+    gains: # Required because we're controlling an effort interface
+      joint1: {p: 100,  d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
+      joint2: {p: 100,  d: 1, i: 1, i_clamp: 1}
+
diff --git a/rrbot_control/launch/rrbot_control.launch b/rrbot_control/launch/rrbot_control.launch
index 0a0c605..a4b1b2a 100644
--- a/rrbot_control/launch/rrbot_control.launch
+++ b/rrbot_control/launch/rrbot_control.launch
@@ -7,7 +7,9 @@
   <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false"
        output="screen" ns="/rrbot" args="joint_state_controller
                                          joint1_position_controller
-                                     joint2_position_controller"/>
+                                   joint2_position_controller
+                                   joint_trajectory_controller
+                                          "/>
 
   <!-- convert joint states to TF transforms for rviz, etc -->
   <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher"
```

but I got have following error. Is it possible to run joint trajectory action while keeping ability to command value to each joint? I remember some real robto (pr2, baxter) has capable of this, so how do the archive that?

```
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1421039041.629407] [242.570000] Failed to start controllers: joint_state_controller, joint1_position_controller, joint2_position_controller, joint_trajectory_controller
[ WARN] [1421039041.629194844, 242.570000000]: Resource conflict on [joint1].  Controllers = [joint1_position_controller, joint_trajectory_controller, ]
[ WARN] [1421039041.629234042, 242.570000000]: Resource conflict on [joint2].  Controllers =    [joint2_position_controller, joint_trajectory_controller, ]
[ERROR] [1421039041.629256800, 242.570000000]: Could not switch controllers, due to resource conflict
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200777/using-both-jointtrajectorycontroller-and-jointpositioncontroller-at-same-time-in-ros_control/) by [Kei Okada](https://answers.ros.org/users/102/kei-okada/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1186 on 2015-01-12

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Is it possible to run joint trajectory action while keeping ability to command value to each joint?

By commanding individual joints you mean the specific ROS API of `JointPositionController`?.

These are the options that currently exist:

- Use the `controller_manager/switch_controller` service to stop the `joint_trajectory_controller` and start the `joint_position_controller` to change the currently running controllers.
- If you normally use the `joint_trajectory_controller`, but sometimes want to change to the `joint_position_controller`, you  can setup a launch file consisting of a [`spawner`](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#spawner) that starts the `joint_position_controller` and an [`unspawner`](http://wiki.ros.org/controller_manager#unspawner) for inhibitting (stopping) the `joint_trajectory_controller`. When you kill the roslaunch process and the `spawner+unspawner` die, you will revert back to the original controller configuration.
- You can use only the `joint_trajectory_controller`. Because it only accepts commands for *all* controller joints and not *some*, you can write a small node that takes in commands and adds the current joint state to the missing joints.

Solutions that don't yet exist:

- Propose an enhancement to the `joint_trajectory_controller` so it can take trajectories not involving all group joints. There are likely subtle points to figure out to get the implementation right.

Solutions that I don't recommend, but you can implement if you want to:

- Override the default [resource conflict policy](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_control/blob/indigo-devel/hardware_interface/include/hardware_interface/robot_hw.h#L73), so resource access is non-exclusive. Take into account that aloowing two controllers to send position commands to the same joint is not the best idea.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2015-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3